# Replacing Vowels With Asterisks

Tags: java, string

I have an assignment where I must take a user-inputted name and convert vowels to asterisks. I have that portion of the assignment down pact (as you'll see in my code below), but there's another part to it: if the entered string has an even amount of characters, there should be two instead of one spaces between the first and last name. If it's odd, it should only be one. I've attempted to implement this with an if-else statement, but it does not work properly.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*; // necessary for user input

    public class Prog510a
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
       String word = input.nextLine();

       int length = word.length();
       String space = "";
       for(int count = 0; count < word.length(); count ++)
       {
           char c = word.charAt(count);
           if(c == 'a' || c == 'A' || c == 'e' || c == 'E' || c == 'i' || c == 'I' || c == 'o' || c == 'O'
           || c == 'u' || c == 'U')
           {
            String front = word.substring(0, count);
            String back = word.substring(count + 1);
            word = front + "*" + back;
           }
       }
        if (length % 2 == 0)
        {
          space = "  ";
        }
        else
        {
          space = " ";
        }

       System.out.println(word);
      }

}
```

Comment: perhaps you should actually do something with 'space' after you assign it.....!

Comment: "it does not work properly" is not helpful to us. What is it doing, exactly?

Comment: It doesn't have any effect on what is printed whatsoever from what I can tell, if that answers your question.

Comment: What could I do with space to make it relevant?

Comment: can you give us an expected output for "the space between the first and last name should be " " ?  I really do not understand what you want?!!!!!!!!

Comment: Example output for "john smith" would be "j*hn  sm*th" because there are 10 (even amount) characters including the space. "joe doe" would be "j** d**"; only one space because there are 7 (odd amount) characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you might want to first split the full name into the first and last name. This can be done using the `split` function, which returns a String array:

```
string[] firstAndLastNames = word.split(" ");
```

This would of course be done after you've replaced the vowels, but it doesn't have to be.

Then you just have to get the length of the full name, and assign to the `space` variable appropriately:

```
if ((firstAndLastNames[0].length() + firstAndLastNames[1].length()) % 2 == 0)
    space = "  ";
else
    space = " ";
```

Then when you output it, do something like:

```
System.out.println(firstAndLastNames[0] + space + firstAndLastNames[1]);
```

I would also reccomend a better way of replacing the vowels with asterisks, because it's quite messy. It might be better to create an array of vowels, and use the `equalsIgnoreCase` function to replace:

```
string[] vowels = {"a","e","i","o","u"};
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++}
    for (int j = 0; j < word.length; j++)
        if (word[j].equalsIgnoreCase(vowel[i]))
            word[j] = "*";
```

Since you haven't learnt arrays yet, you could just use strings `replace` function to replace the space with either one space or two depending on the length, something like:

```
if (word.length() % 2 == 0)
    word = word.replace(" ","  ");
```

You don't need to check if it's odd, because it will already have 1 space, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the informative post, friend! Unfortunately, we have not yet learned how to utilize arrays in my CompSci class. :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter version for you:

```
public class NameVowelsToAsterisks{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String word = input.nextLine();

        String astWord = word.replaceAll("[AEIOUYaeiouy]", "*");  //changing to asterisks

        String spaceWord = new String();
        if (astWord.length() % 2 == 0) {
            int spacePos = astWord.indexOf(' ');    //finding position of space
            spaceWord = new StringBuilder(astWord).insert(spacePos, " ").toString(); //adding space if needed
        } else spaceWord = astWord;

        System.out.println(spaceWord);  //printing result
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't think the first print line is needed, though. It works fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

First i think you should use replace instead of using that big ugly loop.

A tutorial : [java string replace example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/12/java-string-replace-example-tutorial.html)

The documentation : [java api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) : in this one look for the methods replace, replaceAll, replaceFirst

Hope this helps